# Tool for Measuring UNC Path Access Times

Tags: windows, networking, unc

I'm being asked to write a tool that, given a UNC path and a set of credentials, will display the amount of time it took to access the directory.  It then has to get any file in that directory, read it and display how long that took.  This seems like something powershell was made for.  If so, where can I learn more about network access time queries?  If not, are there any other tools that will come close to what I need?

Comment: @Dzejms FWIW, it's a good question here, that I'd really like to know the answer to (everything I can find says it's not possible in PowerShell natively, though) ... just that it has a much, much, much better chance of getting a useful answer over at SO.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard Please don't recommend users cross-post to other sites. If you're going to mention other [se] sites then also mention that Questions can be migrated at the same time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get directory access time this by using these two Powershell commands [Measure-Command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849910.aspx) and [Resolve-Path](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849858.aspx)

Measure-Command { Resolve-Path [Your Path Here] }